# Won't loop reading strings through ObjectInputStream at the client socket

Tags: java, sockets, objectinputstream

I have to send Strings from server to client side by socket at the server side i have following code

```
serverSocket=new ServerSocket(2004);
        socket=serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("request arrived");
        this.outStream=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outStream.flush();
        this.inStream=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

       //PoolTuningStrategy is an terface that is implemented by number of strategies

        for ( PoolTuningStrategy st : this.strategies ) {
                String name=st.getName();
            System.out.println("inside Loop "+name);

              outStream.writeObject(name);
              outStream.flush();
            }

          outStream.writeObject("END NAMES...");
          outStream.flush();
```

Now at the server side all the names are printed on the console correctly. Now at the client side i have the follwing code.

```
socket = new Socket("localhost", 2004);
System.out.println("Client starting");
this.outStream=new  ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
outStream.flush();
this.inStream=new   ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
do{
     name=(String)this.inStream.readObject();
     System.out.println(name);

  }while(name.equals("END NAMES..."));
```

But only first string is printed at the client side, not all!
Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ! in front of your equals() test in the while condition.

There is no 'ambiguity' here.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, make sure you are calling `outStream.close()`. You were also missing the `!`

I would recommend changing your code like this:

```
while( ! "END NAMES...".equals( (name=this.inStream.readObject())) ){
```

OR like this

```
while("END NAMES...".compareTo( (name=this.inStream.readObject())) != 0 ){
      System.out.println(name);

  }
```

Why? 1) By using "END NAMES...".equals(...), you avoid NullPointerException and your code can handle it gracefully. 2) You avoid ClassCastException. 3) You avoid IOException if you are already at the end of the stream. 4) It's leaner code.

Also, it may not be necessary to call flush() if you are calling close() on the stream. It can add extra burden by adding function calls. Note that we are not using C/C++. Java will flush when the buffer is full and at the end (EDIT: when you close it) of the stream automatically.

Comment: You don't avoid EOFException. You can't. It is never necessary to call flush() before close(), but it doesn't add much in the way of 'burden'. The I/O is the burden, by orders of magnitude.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing and if your algorithm calls for it. If your server is talking for a few minute, then you should call flush(). He is also calling it after every item he pushes into the stream. This is NOT C/C++. Java will flush when the buffer is full or when the stream closes. Take advantage of this.

Comment: Calling flush() *immediately* before calling close() is redundant. I don't see what C or C++ have to do with it.

Comment: I think we are talking about the same thing actually. I agree about "Calling flush() immediately before calling close() is redundant".